# Cannot see http (apache) server outside home network

Tags: apache-http-server

Ive been racking my brain with this all evening. Power went out with a tstorm today, started back up my server... running apache and a team speak server on it. TS is great, cant see my web page outside my network!

Firewall is disabled on the pc running it (centos btw), apache is running and working. correct ports are forwarded on my router (my isp blocks port 80). Ive tried changing ports, pretty much everything i can think of. httpd.conf is pointing to the correct addy and port, and my domain is pointing to the correct external ip. Im at a loss, any ideas out there?

Answer (score 0):

Run an external port scan to ensure the correct ports are actually open in your router. Double check the Apache service is up and running and try accessing your website by IP address rather than your domain to rule out DNS issues. That ought to narrow down your problem. It is also likely that your router took a dump on you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Cant access the site outside my network with the ip addy. Also, i cannot see the site from a different pc inside my network now. Changed the dest port to 9999, setup rules on the router to forward 80 and 9999 to the host pc. Also have a forwarding rule 80 -> 9999. Wondering if its godaddy's fault with their dns servers or whats going on.

Comment: hmm. If you can't see it internally that suggests other problems. Can you access your page using http://localhost/ on the server?

Comment: changed the port listened to back to 80, i can see it on my home network once more. So... ive changed the server name to xxxx.com:9999 and the port listened to back to 80 as mentioned. Router still has a rule to forward 80 traffic to 9999. still cannot see it outside my network

Comment: This would not work. If your ISP blocks port 80 like you said, you need to have the server listening on port 9999 with a rule in your router to forward 9999. Also keep in mind that if you want to access your server internally, you need to append the port number after the address within your browser. ie: http://YOURSERVER:9999. By default the browser will try connecting on the standard port. (80) which would not work in your case.

Comment: i now have myserver:9999 as the name in httpd.conf, ports, and forwarding are correct to bypass the port 80 block. works great inside my lan, outside.. not so much

Comment: and with that... listening on port 9999. once again, i can no longer see the website on my network. I can see it hosted on the server its on... 127.0.0.1 or with the domain name. edit- it however works if I put the :9999 port at the end of it. Still refreshing it on devices outside my network to see if this fixes it

Comment: Though its becoming obvious this did not fix it.. I'm about out of idea's here. anyone have anything? throw me a bone here...

Comment: okay... its viewable from the outside... if you put the :9999 at the end of the url. i have a rule that should forward 80 to 9999 still on the router. Has been there since the beginning. Does that mean my router has bit the dust

Comment: Very possible. Try a hard reboot - unplug from wall for about a minute and power on again.

Comment: Yep, ive tried to power cycle it a few times now with no success. Anyone else have any ideas?

Comment: Try by running Apache on a different port and change the router's port forward rule to that port.